# Issue invoking WS-Security Enabled service using camel cxf endpoint - No username available

Tags: apache-camel, cxf-client

I am trying to invoke a third party .net web service with ws-security and I am getting the following exception in spite of configuring all the required parameters in WSS4JOutInterceptor.

**org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No username available 
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.TransportBindingHandler.handleBinding(TransportBindingHandler.java:177)[cxf-rt-ws-security-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessageInternal(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:195)[cxf-rt-ws-security-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]** 
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:114)[cxf-rt-ws-security-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2] 
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:101)[cxf-rt-ws-security-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2] 
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)[cxf-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2] 
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)[cxf-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2] 
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:416)[cxf-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2] 
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.process(CxfProducer.java:112)[camel-cxf-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:120)[camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:416)[camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)[camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:166)[camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:74)[camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1] 
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)[:1.8.0_25] 
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)[:1.8.0_25]

Below is my cxf end point configuration

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="telapoint" 
  address="https://mycompany.com/APIv2/MyService"   wsdlURL="https://mycompany.com/APIv2/MyServices.svc?wsdl">
            <cxf:inInterceptors>
                    <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor" />
            </cxf:inInterceptors>
            <cxf:outInterceptors>
                    <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor" />
                    <ref bean="wss4jOutInterceptor" />
            </cxf:outInterceptors>
            <cxf:properties>
                    <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD" />
            </cxf:properties>
    </cxf:cxfEndpoint</b>> 

<bean id="wss4jOutInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
            <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                            <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken Timestamp" />
                            <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
                            <entry key="user" value="xxxxxx" />
                            <entry key="passwordCallbackClass" 
                                    value="com.mycompany.t.UTPasswordCallback" />
                            <entry key="addUsernameTokenNonce" value="true" />
                            <entry key="addUsernameTokenCreated" value="true" />
                    </map>
            </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

**Below is the Camel Route**

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
trace="false">
<route id="telaPoint_Camel_Route_with_CXF">
    <from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=10m" />
    <setBody>
        <constant>
            <![CDATA[
                   <v2:OrdersGetByStatus   xmlns:v2="http://mycompany.com/TelaFuel/v2">
                         <v2:status>Delivered</v2:status>
                   </v2:OrdersGetByStatus>
            ]]>
        </constant>
    </setBody>
    <setHeader headerName="operationName">
        <constant>OrdersGetByStatus</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <setHeader headerName="operationNamespace">
        <constant>http://mycompany.com/TelaFuel/v2</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="telapoint" />
</route>
</camelContext>
```

Below are my POM depedencies

```
    <properties>
            <camel-version>2.14.1</camel-version>
            <log4j-version>1.2.17</log4j-version>
            <jaxb-api-version>2.2.12</jaxb-api-version>
            <jaxb-impl-version>2.2.11</jaxb-impl-version>
            <cxf-version>3.0.2</cxf-version>
            <log4j-version>1.2.17</log4j-version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${camel-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
                    <version>${camel-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
                    <version>${camel-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
                    <version>${camel-version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
                    <version>${cxf-version}</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
                    <version>${cxf-version}</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
                    <version>${cxf-version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>${log4j-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.5</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
                    <version>${cxf-version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
                    <version>${cxf-version}</version>
            </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

(below is the snippet of the ws-policy from the wsdl)

```
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:TransportToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:HttpToken/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:TransportToken>
<sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Basic256/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<sp:Layout>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Strict/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Layout>
<sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:TransportBinding>
<sp:SignedSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:UsernameToken>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
<sp:Wss11 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:Policy/>
</sp:Wss11>
<sp:Trust10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens/>
<sp:RequireClientEntropy/>
<sp:RequireServerEntropy/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Trust10>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
```

Answer (score 0):

As CXF PAYLOAD dataformate doesn't process the soap header, you may need to change the dataformat to CXF_MESSAGE or POJO to force CXF interceptor to handle those soap header.

Comment: Willem big thank you for your response.  As suggested I have tried changing the dataformat to CXF_MESSAGE/POJO but I still keep getting the no username available error.  Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: Willem any additional thoughts/options on this issue?

Comment: You need to setup the WSS4JOutInterceptor just like this https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-cxf/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/cxf/wssecurity/client/Client.java

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly you are trying to create a SOAP client for a Web Services that includes a `<wsp:Policy>` definition.

This means that you should **not** include any CXF interceptor (e.g. like `WSS4JOutInterceptor`). You should just configure a jaws:client appropriately so as to automatically detect the `<wsp:Policy>` in the WSDL and enable its internal WS Security Policy interceptor. If you define extra ones (as you did) then it will not work at all.

Check out these example:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Web_Services_Security_Guide/files/STS-Demo-Client.html

and

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Web_Services_Security_Guide/files/STS-Demo-Server.html

An example could be:

```
    <jaxws:client
    xmlns:tns="http://www.mynamespace.com/test"
    id="testSecureSoapClient" 
    wsdlLocation="wsdl/should_include_policy__definition.wsdl"
    address="http://localhost:8192/test"
    endpointName="tns:testServicePort" 
    serviceName="tns:testServiceService"
    serviceClass="com.test.TestServicePortType">
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="ws-security.callback-handler">
            <ref component-id="myTestPasswordCallback"/>
        </entry>       
        ...
    </jaxws:properties>
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
    <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
    </jaxws:outInterceptors>
</jaxws:client>
```